# Override BaseWeb's File Uploader button label text

Tags: reactjs, baseweb

Trying to override [File Uploader's](https://baseweb.design/components/file-uploader/) button text, but `ButtonComponent.props` has `any` type, so can't figure out what I am able to pass there. My idea inspired by [Button docs](https://baseweb.design/components/button) was to set `children` property, but button text remains unchanged. Could anyone give a hint?

```
import { FileUploaderProps, FileUploader } from 'baseui/file-uploader';
import React, { FC } from 'react';

const StyledFileUploader: FC<FileUploaderProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <FileUploader
      {...props}
      overrides={{
        ButtonComponent: {
          props: {
            children: 'text',
            overrides: {
              BaseButton: {
                children: 'text',
                props: {
                  children: 'text',
                },
                style: () => ({
                  backgroundColor: '#A4A4A4',
                  color: '#fff',
                  borderRadius: '2px',
                  paddingTop: '3px',
                  paddingRight: '22px',
                  paddingBottom: '3px',
                  paddingLeft: '22px',
                  fontSize: '16px',
                  lineHeight: '20px',
                  ':hover': {
                    backgroundColor: '#A4A4A4',
                    color: '#fff',
                  },
                }),
              },
            },
          },
        },
        FileDragAndDrop: {
          style: () => {
            return {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
              borderRightColor: 'transparent',
              borderTopColor: 'transparent',
              borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
            };
          },
        },
        ContentMessage: {
          style: () => {
            return {
              display: 'none',
            };
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default StyledFileUploader;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can without overriding the whole component. This is weird exception for the `children` props.

Have a look at [this minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-fire-wmcsi?file=/src/StyledFileUploader.jsx). `startEnhancer` will be respected, `children` not:

```
import { FileUploader } from "baseui/file-uploader";
import React from "react";

const StyledFileUploader = (props) => {
  return (
    <FileUploader
      {...props}
      overrides={{
        ButtonComponent: {
          props: {
            startEnhancer: "I'm here!",
            children: "I won't be..."
          }
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default StyledFileUploader;
```

[image: The output from the code above]

The reason can be found in the implementation:

1. `FileUploader` gives `Button` the overrides props [here](https://github.com/uber/baseweb/blob/5e576d4692d257b16595c7fc294ae6c0c2830292/src/file-uploader/file-uploader.js#L139)
2. `Button` ifself passes its own props (`this.props`) to `ButtonInternals` [here](https://github.com/uber/baseweb/blob/5e576d4692d257b16595c7fc294ae6c0c2830292/src/button/button.js#L130)
3. `ButtonInternals` renders its `children` and some other stuff [here](https://github.com/uber/baseweb/blob/5e576d4692d257b16595c7fc294ae6c0c2830292/src/button/button-internals.js#L50)

**But** `FileUploader` passed `{locale.fileuploader.browseFiles}` to the `Button` as `children` [here](https://github.com/uber/baseweb/blob/5e576d4692d257b16595c7fc294ae6c0c2830292/src/file-uploader/file-uploader.js#L141), which is after the `overrides` (and therefore overrides the overrides...)

You may want to file a bug report (so `children` gets put before the override props in `FileUploader`) or just override the whole button component.

Comment: *just* override the whole button component is not an option since it loses click handler - dialog window won't be opened with custom component. therefore, there is no use for this component at all after this change?

Comment: actually, I've found out that it accepts FC with props parameter as well. I will post my answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of accepted answer, I figured out how to override button component. Originally I thought it was not possible (due to component losing click handlers), but `props` is actually carrying it, so we can use `<Button {...props}`

```
export const StyledFileUploader: FC<FileUploaderProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <FileUploader
      {...props}
      overrides={{
        ButtonComponent: (props) => (
          <Button
            {...props}
            overrides={{
              BaseButton: {
                style: () => ({
                  backgroundColor: '#A4A4A4',
                  color: '#fff',
                  borderTopRightRadius: '2px',
                  borderTopLeftRadius: '2px',
                  borderBottomRightRadius: '2px',
                  borderBottomLeftRadius: '2px',
                  paddingTop: '3px',
                  paddingRight: '22px',
                  paddingBottom: '3px',
                  paddingLeft: '22px',
                  fontSize: '16px',
                  lineHeight: '20px',
                  ':hover': {
                    backgroundColor: '#A4A4A4',
                    color: '#fff',
                  },
                }),
              },
            }}
          >
            Upload
          </Button>
        ),
        FileDragAndDrop: {
          style: () => {
            return {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
              borderRightColor: 'transparent',
              borderTopColor: 'transparent',
              borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
            };
          },
        },
        ContentMessage: {
          style: () => {
            return {
              display: 'none',
            };
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To change any text, you should use LocaleProvider: https://baseweb.design/guides/internationalization/

Overriding / replacing components should be the last resort.

Comment: thanks, nice suggestion, have not thought about it. guess it won't work if we need different labels on multiple components

Comment: why? you can have multiple LocaleProviders in the same app

Comment: yes.. I see your point now. Thanks for clarification.